# Problem with mathematical text in xelatex

Tags: xetex

For some reason, the mathematics portion (like sin, cos etc.) of devanagari document is also in devanagari. Here is a mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{AnnapurnaSIL-Regular.ttf}%
[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis,
BoldFont=AnnapurnaSIL-Bold.ttf]
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[Scale=1.2,range=it/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[Scale=1.2,range=up/{num,Latin,latin}]
\begin{document}
    saMkriyaa $\bigtriangledown$ jo $x\bigtriangledown y=x \sin y$  dvaaraa paribhaa.sit hai|
    \(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1\)
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

As one can see the `\sin` and `\cos` appear in devanagari instead of English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\setmathrm`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Kohinoor Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis]

\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\setmathrm{STIX2Math.otf}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\begin{document}

saMkriyaa $\bigtriangledown$ jo $x\bigtriangledown y=x \sin y$  dvaaraa paribhaa.sit hai|
\(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Change back the Devanagari font, I used one on my system.

Comment: Great! It works.

Answer (score 2):

That’s because the operator font is by default `\mathrm`, which is by default `\rmfamily`, which you set to map Latin letters to Devanagari.

Like egreg said, you can fix this with `\setmathrm`, although `unicode-math` also has a `\setoperatorfont` command.  For example, to use sans-serif operator names with the Latin script:

```
\setmathsf{NewComputerModernSans}[Scale=MatchLowercase] % For example.
\setoperatorfont\mathsf
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/203710)

Comment: @AndrewSwann I respectfully disagree. The earlier answer provided only a solution with no explanation, so I explained what was going on. I also provided an alternative solution.

Comment: Currently this looks like a comment on egreg's answer.  Adding complete code and correcting your typos (e.g. `\setmathm`) could certainly change that impression.

Comment: @AndrewSwann First, thank you for noticing the typo.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I’ll add a simple example of `\setoperatorfont`. The original answer mentions egreg’s once, in the second paragraph, as a courtesy. Neither the explanation of the problem nor the second solution have anything to do with his answer.